# Восстановление удаленного раздела Windows 11

Tags: windows

Нужно было установить 11 Винду. У человека был hdd и ssd разделенный на 2 раздела. Чтобы на всякий случай не удалить разделы на hdd(предполагалось что на нём все нужные данные, преимущественно фото), hdd был физически отделен(hdd и ssd имели одинаковый размер, поэтому по объему нельзя было определить). Остался только ssd. На стадии выборе места установки, я на каждом из разделов нажал кнопку удалить. После установки оказалось, что отделенный hdd не содержал те данные, а все фото были на разделе ssd, который был удален. Как можно вернуть данные из того раздела?

Comment: есть софт по восстановлению данных, воспользуйтесь им. Есть небольшая вероятность, что часть данных будет спасена

Comment: @ArchDemon, можно по конкретней. Я например пытался использовать Dmde, но пока ничего не получилось

Comment: после удаления раздела установку продолжили?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recuva

Comment: @eri да, после установки только и заметил

Comment: @ArchDemon, использовал recuva, однако тоже не сильно помогло, или я как и с Dmde что то сделал не так

Comment: Уж не знаю какой у вас объём диска, но это дело не быстрое (хотя на ssd я ни разу не тестил), а прошло всего 14 минут

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_recovery#List_of_data_recovery_software, https://handyrecovery.software